# Uploading logo using Codeigniter not working on editform

Tags: php, image, forms, codeigniter, upload

I have an editform for editing my company information. I also have a field for uploading a logo. When I click on choose file, and click Submit (the form) It stores the filename in my database as imagename.jpg for example.

I also want to add the image to the folder assets/uploads/. I tried it using the codeigniter upload class, same as I did on my other upload form, but this one does not work. I just don't know why.

Here's my editform:

```
<?= form_open_multipart('members/update/'.$id);?>
//other fields for editing company
    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Logo:'); ?></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="logo" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td><?= form_submit('submit', 'Opslaan');?> <?= form_reset('reset', 'Reset');?></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<?= form_close()?>
```

My controller:

```
function update() //de update functie voor bovenstaande functie.
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array(
       'Bedrijfsnaam' => $this->input->post('Bedrijfsnaam'),
       'Postcode' => $this->input->post('Postcode'),
       'Plaats' => $this->input->post('Plaats'),
       'Telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('Telefoonnummer'),
       'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
       'Website' => $this->input->post('Website'),
       'Profiel' => $this->input->post('Profiel'),
       'Adres' => $this->input->post('Adres'),
    );
    if($this->input->post('logo')) { $data['logo'] = $this->input->post('logo'); }
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '';
    $config['max_height']  = '';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    }
    $this->members_model->updatebedrijf($id, $data);

    $b = $this->session->userdata('idbedrijven');
    redirect("members/$b");
}   
function updatebedrijf($id, $data)
{
    foreach($this->input->post('categorieen') as $cat){
        $this->db->where('idbedrijven', $id);
        $this->db->update('bedrijven', $data); 

        $to_bedrijfcategorieen2['idcategorieen'] = $this->input->post('categorieen');
        $this->insert_bedrijfcat1($to_bedrijfcategorieen2); 
    };

}
```

My model:

```
function updatebedrijf($id, $data)
{
    foreach($this->input->post('categorieen') as $cat){
        $this->db->where('idbedrijven', $id);
        $this->db->update('bedrijven', $data); 

        $to_bedrijfcategorieen2['idcategorieen'] = $this->input->post('categorieen');
        $this->insert_bedrijfcat1($to_bedrijfcategorieen2); 
    };

}
```

It just does not upload. The path is the same as my other uploadfunction. that one works fine.

Comment: have you some error message?

Comment: No. It just stores the name in the database but doesn't upload it the the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set field name in the `do_upload` function

```
 if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("logo"))
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
}else{
 $image_data = $this->upload->data();

}
```

And there is one thing wrong you have a if check for `logo` field and you are trying to get in post why ?? it should be

```
if($_FILES['logo']['name'] != '') { $data['logo'] = $_FILES['logo']['name']; }
```

Comment: It's because. of the edit form. when I leave it blank (when editing) it's set to 0. but if I have it like that It does not overwrite it.

Comment: if user do not uploads the file you will not set the `$data['logo']` so your updated query will not override the existing value in db if user uploads then it has the new file name and overrides the previous one simple so whats the problem

Comment: I got that piece of code from another SO user. but your solution is better. Stupid that I did not changed that my own. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload(?))
```

You should set file name as argument to upload function, since it is not default 'userfile'?

Comment: So what am I missing? I don't understand what you mean, because it works great with same code in my other form.

Comment: @KeesSonnema, something like: $config['file_name'] = $filename; and: $this->upload->initialize($config);

Comment: It's not really helping. What exactly are you trying to tell. $this->upload->initialize($config) does not work for the upload lib.

Answer (score 0):

Not any of the solutions woked. This the way that I came up with.

```
if ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != null) {
            // upload configuration
            $upload_config = array(
                'upload_path' => './assets/uploads/',
                'allowed_types' => 'jpeg|jpg|png',
                'max_size' => 1048576,
                'max_width' => 10240,
                'max_height' => 7680,
                'encrypt_name' => TRUE
            );
            // load upload library config
            $this->load->library('upload', $upload_config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
                // assign upload errors
                $data['upload_errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                // load page title
                $page['title'] = "Edit Parent";
                // fetch parent information
                $this->db->select('Database Query');
                // info data in row
                $data['info'] = $this->db->get()->row();
                // load view with page title
                $this->load->view('temp/header', $page);
                $this->load->view('editParents', $data);
                $this->load->view('temp/footer');
            } else {
                $upload_photo = $this->upload->data();
                // profile image
                $parent_photo = $upload_photo['file_name'];
            }
        } else {
            // profile image
            $parent_photo = $this->input->post('profile_image');
        }
```